# Cannot execute SQL

Tags: android

i wanna execute sql like that:

```
DELETE FROM `hosts` WHERE ip = 192.168.0.1 AND port = 22
```

How i try make that:

```
public static void delHost(Context context, String ip, String port) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    /*Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_HOSTS + " WHERE "
            + DBHelper.KEY_IP + " = " + ip + " AND " + DBHelper.KEY_PORT + " = " + port);*/

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM `" + DBHelper.TABLE_HOSTS + "` WHERE " + DBHelper.KEY_IP
            + " = " + ip + " AND " + DBHelper.KEY_PORT + " = " + port);
    //database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_HOSTS, null, contentValues);

    //cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

What i get:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".0": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: DELETE FROM `hosts` WHERE ip = 192.168.0.1 AND port = 22
```

Sql query is right, idk what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Perhaps the ip is being interpreted as a number and not a string by the SQLite query (because it's not wrapped by quotes), try "\"" + ip + "\""

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [EdwynZN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3547212/edwynzn)

```
public static void delHost(Context context, String ip, String port) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM `" + DBHelper.TABLE_HOSTS + "` WHERE " + DBHelper.KEY_IP
            + " = " + "\"" + ip + "\"" + " AND " + DBHelper.KEY_PORT + " = " + "\"" + port + "\"");

    dbHelper.close();
}
```